# How to draw a heat map of New York city community based on certain data using R?

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, colors

For a project I am currently working on, I have to draw a heat map of New York city community based on certain input using R. I googled for this topic and found that in R, there is a package called "map" will allow you to draw a heat map of the states of US pretty easily. However, I have no clue about how to draw similar heat maps for a city, and specifically here, New York city? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this is the community map I would like to start with. I just would like to know how I can change this into a heat map using R? http://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/community/community-portal.page

Comment: Don't use comments to clarify question. Use the edit "button" to open up your question for revisions. At the moment this is insufficient for support a programming effort. You should post a dataset , ranges for plotting, and links to map files..... as an edit. Posting  link to a generic NYC website does not qualify as a specific programming task. I'm not yet voting to close. But if no progress occurs here in a few hours I will.

Comment: the shapefile for the community districts is here http://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/districts-download-metadata.page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many answers on SO to help you with the filling in shapefile polygons with colors. I agree with @42- that you've shown no work/effort but this might be helpful for *others* looking to do something similar with NYC community district data. So, for the greater good:

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(geojsonio)
library(ggplot2)

# this is the geojson of the NYC community districts
URL <- "http://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/arcgis/rest/services/nycd/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson"
fil <- "nyc_community_districts.geojson"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

nyc_districts <- geojson_read(fil, what="sp")

# the @data slot of nyc_districts has 2 fields. BoroCD is the district #
nyc_districts_map <- fortify(nyc_districts, region="BoroCD")

# let's see which id is what
mids <- cbind.data.frame(as.data.frame(gCentroid(nyc_districts, byid=TRUE)), 
                         id=nyc_districts$BoroCD)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=nyc_districts_map, map=nyc_districts_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=mids, aes(x=x, y=y, label=id), size=2)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

```
# example choropleth

# we'll just make the map look like the Flash map on the NYC site
colorize <- function(x) {
  switch(substr(x, 1, 1),
         `1`="#86e3ff",
         `2`="#fffe9b",
         `3`="#ffc75f",
         `4`="#e7ceff",
         `5`="#dffd8b")
}

choro <- data.frame(district=nyc_districts@data$BoroCD,
                    fill=sapply(nyc_districts@data$BoroCD, colorize))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=nyc_districts_map, map=nyc_districts_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=choro, map=nyc_districts_map,
                    aes(fill=fill, map_id=district),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15)
# in a real choropleth you'd make colors map to values
# so i'm definitely leaving you some work to do vs just
# copy/paste for fun and profit
gg <- gg + scale_fill_identity()
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

```
# better color palette
library(viridis)

# make up some fill data
set.seed(1492)
choro <- data.frame(district=nyc_districts@data$BoroCD,
                    fill=sample(100, nrow(nyc_districts@data)))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=nyc_districts_map, map=nyc_districts_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=choro, map=nyc_districts_map,
                    aes(fill=fill, map_id=district),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis(name="Better title\nthan 'fill'")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position=c(0.1,0.5))
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I figured out how to generated the heat map according to values I need. However, following your code won't let me generate a legend for the plot? I have tried everything I can but still I can't figure out how to let the legend to show? Can you give some recommendation on how to do that?

Comment: right. this won't but if you have a numeric value in a data frame use that for `fill=YOURCOLUMN` vs `fill=fill` and use one of the `scale_fill_*` functions

Comment: Hello, since I am really new to R and I tried to use the function you mentioned bu still I can't get the legend and below is the code.  gg <- gg + geom_map(data=df, map=nyc_districts_map,
                    aes(fill=count, map_id=district),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15). Here df is the data frame and count is the column with the numbers. Then I use gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", mid ="green", high = "red", guide = "colourbar"). However, the resulting color is very weird and I still can't get the legend bar.

Comment: updated with a full choropleth example, but this was pretty ambitious being this new to R. There are literally tons of examples on SO and on the internet for filling in polygons from shapefiles (I've written many of them). Hence the strong language in the post.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am getting some errors running the code just as is. For the last two maps, when I try to run `gg` it gives me the following error

`Error in seq_len(nrow(data) - 1) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer`

Comment: then you might want to open up a new question with the exact code & data you're using @AlejandroOchoa